# symfony2 annotation documentation

Tags: symfony, annotations

Where can I find documentation for a complete list of annotations possible for different Symfony2 components?

Example, http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/introduction.html here there's not enough information about "options" of the config and documentation about routing via yml in whole.

The same questions for controller annotations. I've found separate references to different annotations possible in controller(http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html, http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/view.html), but no COMPLETE list of possible annotations.

There MUST be something I'm missing, because people somehow know what options to use and how.

Comment: @Annotations are not only for Symfony2, is a library used by many Frameworks, ORM, Languages, etc, and is also possible to create your own. However if you read all Symfony2 documentation (and of Doctrine2 if you use it) you can find there enough informations to start.

Comment: The thing is - I don't need information "to start". I need to understand how to LOOK UP ALL THE INFORMATION about annotations of different components and how to transfer them(if possible) in yml.

Comment: My "to start" was euphemistic. A complete list of annotations possible grouped in one place simply not exist. I know there are hundreds of pages to read but the point is that you want what you should do namely "Read the Docs". PS: for Yaml is the same thing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find all details about annotation in [SensioFrameworkExtraBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html) documentation (@Route , @Method , @ParamConverter ,@Template ,@Cache and @Security ) 
If you want the list for your Entity you can read [doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html)  .

Comment: Okay, now it's clearer. But what about routing? More specifically, I'm interested in: 1. all options available in routing YML; 2. all annotations possible for entity and how to annnotate same options in yml. 3. all HOOKS AND CALLBACKS annotations available for entities like @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks().

Comment: For routing configuration with YML file you should read  : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html 

for ORM and callbacks you should read : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-haslifecyclecallbacks

Comment: Also, for those who like YML way better then annotations - http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/yaml-mapping.html.

Comment: Additional question - is there a way to set up controller annotations via yml?